# JUnit test of future resultset

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, resultset, future

I have been mocking a test for a function ResultSetFuture, I used a example from [Github](https://gist.github.com/tolbertam/aaec33352f5e42e9d78d) (that works) for testing ResultSetFuture, but the code I am testing/mocking uses `Futures#successfulAsList` as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/jaxkodex/b334b78a497e82db8bc328facb871c81#file-mockexample-java-L34). So in Line 34, the test just halts and never finishes. The code shown below is a portion of the test that halts.

```
ResultSetFuture future = Mockito.mock(ResultSetFuture.class);
Mockito.doReturn(result).when(future).get();
Mockito.doReturn(future).when(session).executeAsync(Mockito.anyString());

ResultSetFuture resultF = session.executeAsync("select value from table where key='a'");

Future<List<ResultSet>> data = Futures.successfulAsList(new ArrayList(){{ add(resultF); }});
List finished = data.get(); //  <---- The test stops here
```

Comment: I don't know enough on this topic, but it is possible that the static method successfulAsList does not call the method you mocked, and then never get a response?

Comment: Yep, i found that it creates listeners so that the first to finish will be added to the response (i guess). How could i mock the event then?
 https://github.com/google/guava/blob/918c9e98f3d06e815507c31764e69c38ad2289ed/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AggregateFuture.java#L159

Comment: It seems strange that you are mocking `session.executeAsync` and then calling it in the same test instead of passing it to the code your testing. That seems unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, the code shown is just the portion where it halts (it's been isolated from the test per se), on my real test, it has more logic that uses the result from `executeAsync`

Comment: if you can find the method that is invoked, mock that one. Otherwise, I'm not sure because I actually don't know the meaning of this test, could it be an idea to use PowerMockito and mock the static method? (I always try to avoid the use of PowerMockito, I always try to avoid static method, but sometimes there is no choice)

Comment: You probably need to mock some method in `future` so that it indicates the execution is finished in the `Future`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the `isDone` method in `future` to indicate that the execution finished and avoid the code halting.

```
ResultSetFuture future = Mockito.mock(ResultSetFuture.class);
Mockito.doReturn(result).when(future).get();
Mockito.doReturn(future).when(session).executeAsync(Mockito.anyString());
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(future).isDone(); //<-- mock to avoid halting

ResultSetFuture resultF = session.executeAsync("select value from table where key='a'");

Future<List<ResultSet>> data = Futures.successfulAsList(Collections.singletonList(resultF));
List finished = data.get(); //  <---- The test stops here
```

Comment: Hi, I did tested mocking these methods, `Mockito.doReturn(result).when(future).getUninterruptibly();` and `Mockito.doReturn(true).when(future).isDone();`. No luck though

Comment: try using `Collections.singletonList(resultF)` instead of `(new ArrayList(){{ add(resultF); }}`

Comment: No luck, the test does not finishes yet :/

Comment: I think you need to mock `Futures.successfulAsList` then. Otherwise, you would be testing `Futures` class which you don't own.

Comment: Hmmm, but that method is a static method (cannot mock it with junit), so, we've resolved it creating a wrapper bean that calls `Futures.successfulAsList` and mock that. (pd: we know we could use PowerMock to mock static methods, but is not a priority now...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mock `isDone` and `addListener` methods:

```java
ResultSetFuture future = Mockito.mock(ResultSetFuture.class);
Mockito.doReturn(result).when(future).get();
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(future).isDone();
Mockito.doAnswer(i -> {
    i.getArgumentAt(1, Executor.class).execute(i.getArgumentAt(0, Runnable.class));
    return null;
}).when(future).addListener(any(), any());
Mockito.doReturn(future).when(session).executeAsync(Mockito.anyString());

ResultSetFuture resultF = session.executeAsync("select value from table where key='a'");

Future<List<ResultSet>> data = Futures.successfulAsList(Collections.singletonList(resultF));
List finished = data.get();
```

`addListener` is needed because `Futures.successfulAsList` add a listener which will complete the future returned by `Futures.successfulAsList`.